# Why ActionLink rendering Querystring values on Dev server, but not on my local environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, query-string, actionlink

I have an MVC project I've been working on in a local Dev environment.

This link is behaving oddly:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Kindergarten", "GradeKTo5", "WhoAreYou", new { grade = "K" }, null)
```

**Local:** `http://localhost:3095/WhoAreYou/GradeKTo5/K`

**Dev:** `http://redacted.org/WhoAreYou/GradeKTo5?grade=K`

I'd like it to work as displayed in local environment. In fact, if I do provide the {controller}/{action}/{grade} formatted URL everything works fine - this is what leads me to believe I'm screwing something up in my use of ActionLink.

In a different partial view, I have the following line of code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(department.Text, ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString(), "WhoAreYou", new { grade, dept = department.Value }, null)
```

What am I missing? Why would the same code render querystring values in one environment, but the appropriate route data values on another?

Comment: Cross-posted to: http://forums.asp.net/p/1850205/5175194.aspx/1?Re+Why+ActionLink+rendering+Querystring+values+on+Dev+server+but+not+on+my+local+environment+

Comment: The only explanation to this is that you do not have the same code deployed on your server as the one running locally. Maybe you have different routing configuration setup on your server. How does your routes setup look by the way?

Comment: The deployment was handled by a TFS build agent and the routing seems to be packaged into the DLL upon deployment.

Here's the routing for that portion of the site:
routes.MapRoute(
                "GradeKTo5", // Route name
                "WhoAreYou/GradeKTo5/{grade}/{dept}/{course}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "WhoAreYou", action = "GradeKTo5", grade = UrlParameter.Optional, dept = UrlParameter.Optional, course = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: Your `dept` parameter cannot be optional. Only **the last** parameter in a route definition can be optional. So if you have this route setup you need to provide a value for the dept parameter in your actionlink.

Comment: Since we don't know the Dept at that time (users start by selecting a grade, then a department based on that initial input) then I suppose I'll need to configure the routing and controller to handle the case where only the grade is known.

Odd, because it works just fine in my Local environment.